# DRIVE ANDROID API Is it impossible to download public files that were not created by my app?

Tags: java, android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I'm trying to capture the download links of some public files from my google drive, but the method `metadataBuffer.getCount()` always returns 0. 
**I saw in other posts that the problem are the scopes**

```
GoogleApiClient.Builder builder = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context);
        builder.addApi(Drive.API);
        builder.addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE);
        builder.setAccountName(EXTRA_ACCOUNT_NAME);
        builder.addConnectionCallbacks(connectionCallbacks);
        builder.addOnConnectionFailedListener(connectionFailedListener);

        googleApiClient = builder.build();
        googleApiClient.connect(); // always connection success
```

but there are only two optons "scopes" apparently `Drive.SCOPE_FILE` and `Drive.SCOPE_FOLDER`.

```
private ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult> metadataBufferCallback = new ResultCallback<DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(@NonNull DriveApi.MetadataBufferResult metadataBufferResult) {
        MetadataBuffer metadataBuffer = metadataBufferResult.getMetadataBuffer();

        int count = metadataBuffer.getCount(); // <--- always return 0
        Log.d(TAG, "count " + count);
    }
};
```

**what should I do to view all files in a public folder using Drive API v3?**

Comment: "DRIVE ANDROID API Is it impossible to download public files that were not created by my app?" 
- yes it's impossible

Comment: So this API is only to store app data? This API is almost useless!!! Thanks brother!

Comment: It really depends on the use case. There are a large number of Drive apps that simply need to access files that they themselves created, and for which drive.file is perfect. As a developer, we shouldn't ask for more permission than we need. For the category of Drive app that wants to access all of a user's files (ie. drive scope), there is always the REST API which works very well.

Comment: You can also use OpenFileActivity to let users authorize access to their files. For example, an image editor app may invoke this activity to select an image in the user's Drive to edit. See: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/drive/OpenFileActivityBuilder